# Boot error message

Tags: boot, 9.10, dmesg

I'm getting following error message at the system boot up. The system takes long time to start and I could not understand what it's saying and why. The os has recently been installed(3 weeks ago). The following are the last few line of /var/log/dmesg file. Please any one let me know if it could be resolved. Thank you!

```
[   10.049830] type=1505 audit(1295344306.586:13): operation="profile_replace" pid=850 name=/usr/share/gdm/guest-session/Xsession
[   10.051165] type=1505 audit(1295344306.586:14): operation="profile_replace" pid=851 name=/sbin/dhclient3
[   10.051744] type=1505 audit(1295344306.586:15): operation="profile_replace" pid=851 name=/usr/lib/NetworkManager/nm-dhcp-client.action
[   10.052058] type=1505 audit(1295344306.590:16): operation="profile_replace" pid=851 name=/usr/lib/connman/scripts/dhclient-script
[   10.055205] type=1505 audit(1295344306.590:17): operation="profile_replace" pid=852 name=/usr/bin/evince
[   10.064843] type=1505 audit(1295344306.602:18): operation="profile_replace" pid=852 name=/usr/bin/evince-previewer
[   10.070323] type=1505 audit(1295344306.606:19): operation="profile_replace" pid=852 name=/usr/bin/evince-thumbnailer
[   10.078696] type=1505 audit(1295344306.614:20): operation="profile_replace" pid=854 name=/usr/lib/cups/backend/cups-pdf
[   10.079377] type=1505 audit(1295344306.614:21): operation="profile_replace" pid=854 name=/usr/sbin/cupsd
[   10.081306] type=1505 audit(1295344306.618:22): operation="profile_replace" pid=855 name=/usr/sbin/mysqld
[   19.476007] eth0: no IPv6 routers present
[   42.816048] ata3: lost interrupt (Status 0x50)
[   42.816073] ata3.00: exception Emask 0x10 SAct 0x0 SErr 0x4850002 action 0xe frozen
[   42.816162] ata3: SError: { RecovComm PHYRdyChg CommWake LinkSeq DevExch }
[   42.816229] ata3.00: cmd c8/00:20:f7:2c:a0/00:00:00:00:00/e2 tag 0 dma 16384 in
[   42.816230]          res 40/00:00:00:00:00/00:00:00:00:00/00 Emask 0x14 (ATA bus error)
[   42.816311] ata3.00: status: { DRDY }
[   42.816337] ata3: hard resetting link
[   43.700050] ata3: SATA link up 3.0 Gbps (SStatus 123 SControl 300)
[   43.732364] ata3.00: configured for UDMA/133
[   43.732371] ata3.00: device reported invalid CHS sector 0
[   43.732381] ata3: EH complete
[   74.804023] ata3: lost interrupt (Status 0x50)
[   74.804049] ata3.00: exception Emask 0x10 SAct 0x0 SErr 0x40d0002 action 0xe frozen
[   74.804137] ata3: SError: { RecovComm PHYRdyChg CommWake 10B8B DevExch }
[   74.804217] ata3.00: cmd c8/00:20:9f:a6:a1/00:00:00:00:00/e2 tag 0 dma 16384 in
[   74.804218]          res 40/00:00:00:00:00/00:00:00:00:00/00 Emask 0x14 (ATA bus error)
[   74.804296] ata3.00: status: { DRDY }
[   74.804322] ata3: hard resetting link
[   75.684548] ata3: SATA link up 3.0 Gbps (SStatus 123 SControl 300)
[   75.716346] ata3.00: configured for UDMA/133
[   75.716353] ata3.00: device reported invalid CHS sector 0
[   75.716363] ata3: EH complete
[  106.804020] ata3: lost interrupt (Status 0x50)
[  106.804045] ata3.00: exception Emask 0x10 SAct 0x0 SErr 0x4050002 action 0xe frozen
[  106.804132] ata3: SError: { RecovComm PHYRdyChg CommWake DevExch }
[  106.804209] ata3.00: cmd c8/00:18:87:c0:cc/00:00:00:00:00/e1 tag 0 dma 12288 in
[  106.804210]          res 40/00:00:00:00:00/00:00:00:00:00/00 Emask 0x14 (ATA bus error)
[  106.804288] ata3.00: status: { DRDY }
[  106.804313] ata3: hard resetting link
[  107.684547] ata3: SATA link up 3.0 Gbps (SStatus 123 SControl 300)
[  107.716346] ata3.00: configured for UDMA/133
[  107.716352] ata3.00: device reported invalid CHS sector 0
[  107.716362] ata3: EH complete
[  138.804019] ata3: lost interrupt (Status 0x50)
[  138.804043] ata3: limiting SATA link speed to 1.5 Gbps
[  138.804050] ata3.00: exception Emask 0x10 SAct 0x0 SErr 0x40d0002 action 0xe frozen
[  138.804137] ata3: SError: { RecovComm PHYRdyChg CommWake 10B8B DevExch }
[  138.804215] ata3.00: cmd c8/00:10:07:42:aa/00:00:00:00:00/e2 tag 0 dma 8192 in
[  138.804216]          res 40/00:00:00:00:00/00:00:00:00:00/00 Emask 0x14 (ATA bus error)
[  138.804294] ata3.00: status: { DRDY }
[  138.804320] ata3: hard resetting link
[  139.684548] ata3: SATA link up 1.5 Gbps (SStatus 113 SControl 310)
[  139.716341] ata3.00: configured for UDMA/133
[  139.716348] ata3.00: device reported invalid CHS sector 0
[  139.716358] ata3: EH complete
[  170.804017] ata3: lost interrupt (Status 0x50)
[  170.804041] ata3.00: exception Emask 0x10 SAct 0x0 SErr 0x48d0002 action 0xe frozen
[  170.804129] ata3: SError: { RecovComm PHYRdyChg CommWake 10B8B LinkSeq DevExch }
[  170.804214] ata3.00: cmd c8/00:20:97:1a:20/00:00:00:00:00/e2 tag 0 dma 16384 in
[  170.804215]          res 40/00:00:00:00:00/00:00:00:00:00/00 Emask 0x14 (ATA bus error)
[  170.804293] ata3.00: status: { DRDY }
[  170.804319] ata3: hard resetting link
[  171.684548] ata3: SATA link up 1.5 Gbps (SStatus 113 SControl 310)
[  171.716360] ata3.00: configured for UDMA/133
[  171.716367] ata3.00: device reported invalid CHS sector 0
[  171.716377] ata3: EH complete
[  203.804025] ata3: lost interrupt (Status 0x50)
[  203.804051] ata3.00: exception Emask 0x10 SAct 0x0 SErr 0x48d0002 action 0xe frozen
[  203.804141] ata3: SError: { RecovComm PHYRdyChg CommWake 10B8B LinkSeq DevExch }
[  203.804222] ata3.00: cmd c8/00:08:6f:44:81/00:00:00:00:00/e0 tag 0 dma 4096 in
[  203.804223]          res 40/00:00:00:00:00/00:00:00:00:00/00 Emask 0x14 (ATA bus error)
[  203.804302] ata3.00: status: { DRDY }
[  203.804328] ata3: hard resetting link
[  204.684051] ata3: SATA link up 1.5 Gbps (SStatus 113 SControl 310)
[  204.716357] ata3.00: configured for UDMA/133
[  204.716363] ata3.00: device reported invalid CHS sector 0
[  204.716373] ata3: EH complete
```

Comment: Maybe hardware issue: SATA-cable? Any reason for installing 9.10 and not 10.04 LTS?

Comment: 9.10 worked fine for the web developers so can't trust new releases 10.04 & 10.10

Comment: So my first try is checking the sata cable

Comment: In 9.10 there are some still open bugs related to ata disk access. As support for 9.10 ends in April 2011 they may never be fixed. If changing cable doesn't help I recommend you try to get your applications running on 10.04 rather than filing a bug against 9.10.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks to be a harddrive error(because of ATA errors).  What worked for me when I had an error like this is loading to a bootable cd and runing

```
fsck /dev/sda1
```

This fix the filesystem problem which was preventing my friends system from booting.

I would also run smart test on the drive to see if it needs replacing.

Comment: I should try this...

Comment: Yeah, `e2fsck -c /dev/sda1`, sda2, sda3... tried to fix it and the system booting normally for now. But I still doubt the HD, as it said HD has many bad blocks and should be replaced; while fixing the bad blocks.

Answer (score 2):

I can only guess that the issue is hardware related since the log shows very terminal errors contacting the disk. Check your computer's internal connections.

If it's not that, then you have serious issues which need to be reported as bugs (but check cables first). There is no answer really to such issues as if it is a bug, it just needs to be fixed by someone. See here for details:

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ReportingBugs

Comment: Filing a bug against 9.10 has little chance to get noticed or even fixed if later releases are not affected.

Comment: Then the bug's been fixed.

Comment: If the bug was fixed e.g. in kernel 2.6.32-xx or later then the fix will never reach 9.10. using kernel 2.6.31-xx

Comment: Yes, and thus using 9.10 is impossible and should not be considered.